# How to set angularjs ng-controller in the rails form_for view

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to use Angularjs in rails app using angularjs-rails gem . Here I am going to include form (directive in module ng ) in rails form view.

I dont know how to inset  **ng-controller="Ctrl"** in the **<%= form_for(@result) do |f| %>**

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert html attributes to the form_for helper in rails

> { "ng-controller" => "Ctrl" } do |f| %>

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried like this <%= form_for(@blog { "ng-controller" => "Ctrl" } ) do |f| %> it show sytax error

Comment: Try <%= form_for @blog, :html => { "ng-controller" => "Ctrl" } do |f| %>